# How to quantify sensitivity in time series model?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

X and Y are time series of length T. X is the predictor and Y is the response. A linear model is fitted as follows:

$$\hat{Y_t}=\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\beta_iX_{t-i}}$$

where $\beta$'s and $\alpha$ are such that they minimise squared errors between $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$.

Now I want to know **"How sensitive is $\hat{Y}$ to X?"**

In an ordinary linear regression (without the temporally lagged quantities on the right), the answer would just be $\beta$, but here I have $N$ different $\beta$'s. Are there ways in which I can condense the$N$ different $\beta$'s into a scalar quantity? Or any other method to answer **"How sensitive is $\hat{Y}$ to X?"**

Potentially relevant information but ignore if not needed:

1. X and Y vectors are highly auto-correlated. For example, X is daily temperature, and Y is daily ice cream sales.
2. When I say "How sensitive is $\hat{Y}$ to X?", I mean how much is Y affected for changes in X. For example, ice cream sales would likely be very sensitive to daily lagged temperature, but laptop sales would probably be insensitive to daily lagged temperature.

Comment: Just note this is not an autoregression since there is no lagged $Y$ on the right hand side. That does not help answer the question, though.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I did not know that. I have replaced the word "autoregression" with "timeseries" in the title.

Comment: Great question! Never thought about such a question! Thank you for sharing your question ;-).

Comment: There's really no reason to "...condense the N different β's into a scalar quantity..." and any suggestion for doing this will necessarily lose information. As you say, standard linear model interpretation already tells you that one unit change in the $i$-th lag $X_i$ leads to $\beta_i$ change in $Y$. (This is a special case of the impulse response function, which can be considered for general VAR models. Your model is a special case of a VAR with certain zero restrictions. It would not be reasonable to try to transform the IRF into a scalar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of $Y_t$ to a unit shock in $X_{t-1}$ is $\beta_1$ and so on for the rest of the lags present. You could consider the cumulative effect on $Y_t$. But this, of course, reflects the impact of an event (an isolated unit shock at some moment in the past) which is highly unlikely, since you tell us that $X$ is highly autocorrelated.

That's the reason why response functions are usually computed for unit shocks in the innovations.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question we should cast your equation (I am using different notation)

$$y_t = w_0 + \sum_{n=1}^Nw_nx_{t-n}$$

into a different formulation.

Let us introduce $\mathbf{w} = [w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_N]^T$ and $\mathbf{x}_t = [x_{t-1}, x_{t-2},\ldots, x_{t-N}]^T$.

Hence, we obtain

$$y_t = w_0 + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_t.$$

We have the dot product between $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}_t$. We know that this will be zero when $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}_t$ are orthogonal.

Hence, we note that the sensitivity of $y_t$ due to changes in $\mathbf{x}_t$ is depending on the weights $\mathbf{w}$.

For orthogonal $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}_t$ the effect on $y_t$ will be $0$.
If $\mathbf{x}_t$ is colinear to $\mathbf{w}$ we get greatest change in $y_t$.

In order to visualize what is happening. Let us simplify to a two-dimensional case. We also assume that $\mathbf{x}_t$ has unit length (see picture $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$). Scaling $\mathbf{x}_t$ will only scale the sensitivity by the same amount.

[image]

The red arrow is the projection of $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_t$ onto $\mathbf{w}$ is a measure of (unit) sensitivity.